# Draw figure on top of an other figure in Kivy language

Tags: kivy

I'm was trying to draw a green rectangle inside of the red rectangle in .kv file. But I see only a red rectangle, maybe green rectangle is hidden behind.

how could I solve this problem?
Thanks

:

```
canvas:

    Color:
        rgb: 1, 0, 0
    Rectangle:
        pos: 0, 0
        size: 300, 300

        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: 100, 100
            pos: self.center_x, self.center_y
```

Answer (score 0):

- Align the graphics instructions e.g. Color, Rectangle, etc.
- Change the `pos` position for the second rectangle

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.1

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red colour
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, 0
                size: 300, 300

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 1, 0, 1     # green colour
            Rectangle:
                size: 100, 100
                pos: 100, 100
'''))
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand that I can't draw inside of figure using alignment. I can do this with the command that you showed me: "canvas.before:". Thanks

Comment: If my answer have helped you. Please remember to accept and/or up-vote the answer. Thank you.